# geom_count with stat="idenity" doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to use the "identity" stat in geom_count?

You can do it with geom_bar():

```
data.frame(color = c("red", "green"),
                num = c(100, 50)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color, num)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

And this returns

[image: 1]

But when I try something similar with geom_count():

```
data.frame(color = c("red", "green", "red", "green"), 
  cut = c("good", "terrible", "terrible", "good"),
  values = c(10, 200, 4, 130)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color, cut)) +
  geom_count(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = color), 
             stat = "identity")
```

I get:
[image: 2]

?

Comment: `geom_count(stat = "identity")` is the same thing as `geom_point()`. `geom_count()` is a convenience wrapper around `geom_point(stat = "sum")`. What output would you have expected to get?

Comment: I thought that it would scale the points by the `values` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scale the area of points to some value, you could use the `size` aesthetic. To make the area (instead of the radius) map to the variable, you can use `scale_size_area()`.

```
data.frame(color = c("red", "green", "red", "green"), 
           cut = c("good", "terrible", "terrible", "good"),
           values = c(10, 200, 4, 130)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color, cut)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = color, size = values)) +
  scale_size_area(limits = c(0, 200), max_size = 20)
```

[image]